# BizTalk integration with google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am looking to integrate BizTalk 2010 with google drive to do the basic operations such as Create folders, upload files, share and change the permissions. Anyone has any idea about it?

Comment: Seen https://zapier.com/zapbook/biztalk/google-drive/ ?

Comment: @rickythefox If you read that page is actually a proposed project and they want someone to actually create it.  There are other integration projects with Google Drive there that may help though.  https://zapier.com/app/explore?services=google-drive

Comment: http://www.rssbus.com/biztalk/google/ 
RSSBus BizTalk Adapter for Google V3
The latest Google BizTalk Adapter release features powerful new updates, including all new support for Google AdWords and Google Drive.

Comment: Yes, Ricky, Zapier's was a proposed project. they dont have the solution yet. But RSS seem to have an adapter. But their trial version is expired and useless. Was wondering what are the charges for their license? any idea Dijkrraaf? Had a look at a sample where they try to connect to Twitter API. Wondering if anyone has a schema for Drive inputs too?

Comment: [Google Drive API HTTP Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

[BizTalk HTTP Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561927.aspx)

Comment: Hi parrotsquawk, did you try working it out using BizTalk HTTP adapter?

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk is primarily a messaging platform, not a folder / file management platform. You can send messages to file location, but any file or folder creation that goes further than writing the file will to custom. Perhaps BizTalk is not the best solution for that problem.

However; If you can mount your Google drive as a local file system, than you can let BizTalk work against the mounted filesystem.

This way you won't have to deal with all the specifics of the Google drive API, and you can focus on your BizTalk solution.

Alternatively, if you cannot mount the drive as a filesystem, just let BizTalk write to a local folder, and synch that folder with your Google drive.